# Kotlin code not getting compiled in my IntelliJ and getting errors when doing Maven install

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am using a mix of Java and Kotlin code in my project. I converted some of my new Java classes to Kotlin using the *"convert Java file to Kotlin file"* option in IntelliJ IDEA.

When I try to Maven build my project, I am getting *"cannot find symbol"* everywhere I use the new converted files.

This is my class converted to Kotlin

```kotlin
open class ListConverter<AnyTypeList> {

    private val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) // ISODate
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        .registerModule(ParameterNamesModule())
        .registerModule(Jdk8Module())
        .registerModule(KotlinModule())

    fun transformToType(attributeValue: AttributeValue): List<AnyTypeList> {
        try {
            val json = attributeValue.s()
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, object : TypeReference<List<AnyTypeList>>() {})
        } catch (e: JsonProcessingException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to convert AttributeValue to list ", e)
        }
    }

    fun transformFromType(inputs: List<AnyTypeList>?): AttributeValue {
        return if (inputs == null) {
            AttributeValue.builder().nul(true).build()
        } else try {
            val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputs)
            AttributeValue.builder().s(json).build()
        } catch (e: JsonProcessingException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Failed to convert list to AttributeValue", e)
        }
    } 
}
```

I have used this in my Java class

```java
public class AConverter extends AnyTypeListConverter<A> {
    
    public List<A> transformTo(B attributeValue) {
        return transformToType(attributeValue);
    } 
}
```

and I am getting errors even at the imports.

```
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
 -------------------------------------------------------------   
 [ERROR] /C:/model/a/AConverter.java:[5,12] cannot find symbol
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: You need to show us some code and error messages.

Comment: updated the question with the code. I hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: And please include some error messages.

Comment: The code block after "and I have used this in my java class" does not show that you used the `ListConverter` written in Kotlin. Did you mean to write `public class AConverter extends ListConverter<A>`?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, also I have called a method from the super class.

Comment: Note that the Java-to-Kotlin converter is a bit rough-and-ready; its output usually needs some manual clean-up, and may not even compile. (That doesn't prevent it being a very useful too, however.)

Comment: Can you attach a link to a sample project?